# Change parent div to active when child is active

Tags: javascript, css, collapsable

I'm working on a CSS Collapsible menu that I created from the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol).

I have a container div that has a button (accordion), that when active, displays content (panel div).

When the button is active, I want to put a border around the container div.

Is there a way I can set .container to active when the child (accordion) is active, so I can target it? Or is there an easier way in CSS?

Any advice anyone has is appreciated. I just can't seem to make it work :(

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Button text</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all the HTML, CSS and Javascript in only one code snippet so that they all together.

Comment: Just do what you did for the panel and add a CSS class to the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.container.active` class, and toggle it from the JS with `this.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');`.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.container.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Button text</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Test 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Button text</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Test 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Button text</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Test 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I have multiple containers and the active class is only added to the first one for some reason :(

Comment: @mark914, I've added another two containers to my answer, and I think it does it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the listener

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")
        .classList.toggle("active");
```

And add these css rule

```
.container {
   border: 0px solid white;
}

.container.active {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```